# Angular 6 - Error is returned when logging in a registered user- how do I resolve it?

Tags: angular, authentication, data-binding, event-handling, mean

I am relatively new to Angular and I've started learning authentication and so I have been trying to set up authentication for my own Angular application.

Registration works and successfully navigates to the route I provide upon success. However, logging in with the correct credentials produces an error which I have defined with a console log.

What exactly am I missing?

-

**Console Error**

> Error on user login: [object Object]

-

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('./models/User')
const Idea = require('./models/Idea');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/example-app', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () =>
{
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
});

// ***************************** \\
//  USER REQUESTS
// ***************************** \\

// Post (create) new user
router.route('/register').post((req,res) =>
{
  let userData = new User(req.body);
  userData.save()
    .then(createdUser =>
    {
      res.status(200).json({'User': 'New user was added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(err =>
    {
      res.status(400).send('Failed to create new user');
    });
});

// Post (login) existing user
router.route('/login').post((req,res) =>
{
  let userData = req.body;
  User.findOne({email: userData.email}, (err, foundUser) =>
  {
    if(err)
    {
      console.log("Error attempting to login: " + err);
    }
    else
    {
      if(!foundUser)
      {
        res.status(401).send("Email is not registered with us.");
      }
      else if(foundUser.password !== userData.password)
      {
        res.status(401).send("Invalid Password");
      }
      else
      {
        res.status(200).send('Login Successful');
      }
    }
  });
});


// ***************************** \\
//  IDEA REQUESTS
// ***************************** \\

// Get all existing ideas
router.route('/ideas').get((req,res) =>
{
  Idea.find((err,foundIdeas) =>
  {
    if(err)
    {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
      res.json(foundIdeas);
    }
  })
});

// Get specific existing idea
router.route('/ideas/:id').get((req,res) =>
{
  Idea.findById(req.params.id, (err,foundIdea) =>
  {
    if(err)
    {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
      res.json(foundIdea);
    }
  });
});

// Post (create) new idea
router.route('/ideas/add').post((req,res) =>
{
  let ideaData = new Idea(req.body);
  ideaData.save()
    .then(createdIdea =>
    {
      res.status(200).json({'idea': 'New idea was added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(err =>
    {
      res.status(400).send('Failed to create new record');
    });
});

// Post (edit) specific existing idea
router.route('/ideas/update/:id').post((req,res) =>
{
  Idea.findById(req.params.id, (err,foundIdea) =>
  {
    if(!foundIdea)
    {
      return next(new Error('Could not find or load document'));
    }
    else
    {
      foundIdea.title = req.body.title;
      foundIdea.textBox1 = req.body.textBox1;
      foundIdea.textBox2 = req.body.textBox2;
      foundIdea.textBox3 = req.body.textBox3;
      foundIdea.textBox4 = req.body.textBox4;
      foundIdea.textBox5 = req.body.textBox5;
      foundIdea.textBox6 = req.body.textBox6;

      foundIdea.save()
        .then(foundIdea =>
        {
          res.json('Idea updated successfully')
        })
        .catch(err =>
        {
          res.status(400).send('Failed to update existing record');
        });
    }
  });
});

// Get (delete) specific existing idea
router.route('/ideas/delete/:id').get((req,res) =>
{
  Idea.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}, (err,foundIdea) =>
  {
    if(err)
    {
      res.json(err);
    }
    else
    {
      res.json('Delete idea successfully');
    }
  });
});



app.use('/', router);

app.get('/', (req,res) => res.send('Connected to Server!'));

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Connected to Express (Port: 4000)"));
```

-

**auth.service.ts [snippet]**

```
export class AuthService {

  private _uri = 'http://localhost:4000';

  private _registerUri = `${this._uri}/register`;
  private _loginUri = `${this._uri}/login`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Register new user to database
  registerUser(user)
  {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this._registerUri}`, user);
  }

  // Login new user to database
  loginUser(email: String, password: String)
  {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this._loginUri}`, {email: email, password: password});
  }
```

-

**login.component.html**

```
div class="container">
  <h1 id="h_Login">Sign Into Your Account</h1>
  <div class="row" id="main-content">
    <form class="col-8 mx-auto" id="col_FormContent">
      <div class="form-group section">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" [(ngModel)]="loginUserData.email" name="email"  #email="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group section">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" [(ngModel)]="loginUserData.password" name="password"  #password="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div class="section_Buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-m btn-block" type="submit" (click)="loginUser()">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

-

**login.component.ts [snippet]**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginUserData: any = {};
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {}


  // EVENT HANDLER - (Login Button) Verify and Login user from database
  loginUser()
  {
    this.authService.loginUser(this.loginUserData.email, this.loginUserData.password)
      .subscribe(
        res =>
        {
          console.log("Login was successful");
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        },
        err =>
        {
          // **** THE ERROR THAT IS RETURNED **** \\
          console.log("Error on user login: " + err);
        }
      );
  }

}
```

-

**User.js (server-side User model Schema)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let User = new Schema({
  email: { type: String },
  password: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Comment: can you include the `User.findOne` method ?

Comment: @Hussein .findOne() is a Mongoose API method: 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html 

Perhaps my understanding of it is lacking?

Comment: i think it's not angular related problem, it's on the server-side, can you include the schema of the `User` model ?

Comment: also paste the output of this here:
`let _err = JSON.parse(err);
console.log("Error on user login: " , _err);`

Comment: I have added the User.js file contents which define the User model schema to the end of the question. Also, I get the following output after applying the above: `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: if you are using chrome, the check the network tab in dev tools, and see there the request going to the login route and the response

Comment: The response according to the Network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools shows "Login Successful"

Comment: can you do this again ?
`let _err = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(err));
console.log(_err);`

Comment: Applying the stringify method as above results in the following:

`{headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4000/login", ok: false, …}
error: {error: {…}, text: "Login Successful"}
headers: {normalizedNames: {…}, lazyUpdate: null}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4000/login"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:4000/login"
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return json in the response:

```
router.route('/login').post((req,res) =>
{
  let userData = req.body;
  User.findOne({email: userData.email}, (err, foundUser) =>
  {
    if(err)
    {
      console.log("Error attempting to login: " + err);
    }
    else
    {
      if(!foundUser)
      {
        res.status(401).send("Email is not registered with us.");
      }
      else if(foundUser.password !== userData.password)
      {
        res.status(401).send("Invalid Password");
      }
      else
      {
        res.status(200).json({'result':'Login Successful'});
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Applying this gives me the error `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.` Is it because I am missing an import?

Comment: if it didn't work can you include the full code for the `server.js` ?

Comment: The same console error returns as per the question, unfortunately. I have added the full content of server.js file. The 'ideas' routes work fine, as too does 'register'. Also I would like to thank you for sticking around throughout this headache! :)

Comment: Beautifully done, that worked (although, just to point out so you can edit the final answer, your forgot the curly-braces in `res.status(200).json({'result':'Login Successful'});` A huge thank you, sir! :)